# dmenu-like X program, but with dynamically generated results

Tags: software-rec, dmenu

I really love the simplicity of dmenu, but unfortunately it's a bit limiting for things that would benefit greatly from (or be impossible without) dynamically generated results. For example, using search suggestions, a more specialized sorting method, or a grep search where nothing is known in advance. Is there a program that would allow me to display my own results based on what is typed into a program similar to dmenu?

Comment: Most desktop environments offer searching through installed programs using `Alt + F2`.

Comment: @zer0rest: that's the kind of thing that dmenu is perfect for, though. Filtering a list of installed programs, or man pages, or any predetermined list. Maybe this is a good time to mention that I'm not using a DE, just i3-wm (and gnome-terminal, and firefox, and pcmanfm, etc, etc).

Comment: dmenu is usually what most people use in standalone window managers, I am using it in awesome-wm, maybe this list might be of interest. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications/Other#Application_launchers

Comment: How about `dmenu`? It gets its completion list from stdin, so you should be able to generate whatever you want.

Comment: @Bandrami: I suppose I didn't explain very well. I want something that is *like* dmenu, but where I can generate a different set of completions based on what the user has already typed in, instead of the automatic filtering.

Comment: Incremental output http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/incremental and non-blocking stdin http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/non_blocking_stdin are the two patches to dmenu that let you do that. (Sorry, I've used them so long I forgot they aren't in the main source tree.)

Comment: try pyo a pthon program that works with dmenu
[website](http://clojurehackers.com/p/tomasstorck/pyo)